# E Failed to getEnergyData

Tags: android, firebase

I wanna register a user in firebase firestore but when I click the register button nothing happens. I don't understand where I went wrong . It doesn't even create the user or send the data to the database

````
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        signi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String mail = regemail.getText().toString().trim();
                String pin = pass.getText().toString().trim();
                String confarm = confir.getText().toString().trim();
                String phon = tele.getText().toString().trim();

                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail, pin).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(registrations.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                            user.put("Email", mail);
                            user.put("Password", pin);
                            user.put("Phone", phon);
                            df.collection("users")
                                    .add(user)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                                        }
                                    });
                            startActivity(new Intent(registrations.this, login.class));
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(registrations.this, "Registration Failed!" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();```

It was working before. I was able to create user and sign in but moving that data to the database is the problem. Also I had used realtime database before and it worked but it was overwtiting the data in the database when I tried to register a new user so I decided to use firestore instead
````

Comment: anything in logs?

Comment: I actually just deleted everything and started over